How to Monkey Patch Js Class Constructor
I am fairly new to js and I have a problem that seems I can solve by modifying the constructor of the base class. This patch here is not applied


// original class in lib
class BasePrinter {
  constructor() {
    console.log("BasePrinter constructor");
  }
}

// patching
function patchBasePrinter() {
  const originalConstructor = BasePrinter.prototype.constructor;

  BasePrinter.prototype.constructor = function(...args) {
    console.log("Patched constructor logic before");

    originalConstructor.apply(this, args);

    console.log("Patched constructor logic after");
  };
}

// Apply the patch
patchBasePrinter();

const printer = new BasePrinter(); 
// Output: BasePrinter constructor

// Expected Output:
// Patched constructor logic before
// BasePrinter constructor
// Patched constructor logic after



The other posts ive seen on this are either inconclusive or end with a solution of patching a method instead.
The real use case is to apply new logic when any class property is changed. The system is already reactive. I just want to add new logic and all the techniques I can find have to do with patching the constructor class

"This does not work" - why not? What happens instead? What's the expected behaviour?

I have edited the code for clarity. Basically the patch is not applied

does the patched constructor need to run before the original constructor? If not, I may have a solution based on this similar question

@JaromandaX no it dosen't.

Based on this similar question, with a little extra work, this could do what you need.
For example:


class BasePrinter {
    constructor() {
        console.log("BasePrinter constructor");
    }
}
class X extends BasePrinter {
    constructor(...args) {
        console.log("Before original constructor - usual limitations apply for extended class");
        super(...args);
        console.log("Your logic here");
    }
}

X.prototype = BasePrinter.prototype;
X.prototype.constructor = X;
BasePrinter = X;
new BasePrinter



